# How to reuse model as parent

Tags: flutter, dart

I get a `json` response in sample format like below

```
// call 1 : /all-users
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "All Users list",
  "data": [{
    "code": "USR001",
    "name": "User One"
  }]
}


// call 2 - /user-details/USR001
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "User Details of USR001",
  "data": {
    "code": "USR001",
    "firstName": "User",
    "lastName": "One",
    "email": "userOne@email.com",
  }
}
```

And my `ApiResponse` model is

```
class ApiResponse {
  bool success;
  String message;
  List<Data> data;

  ApiResponse({this.success, this.message, this.data});

  ApiResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    success = json['success'];
    message = json['message'];
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = new List<Data>();
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data.add(new Data.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }
}
```

The `data` in the response may be an object or array depends on the call. I would like to reuse the `ApiResponse` model for both calls by extending the `data` as separate models. But i don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

I think the *easiest* way would be to simply have two classes that extend `ApiResponse`, and both can call your super.fromJson. Since data will differ, you can do one of two things:

- Pull `data` out into the new derived classes, and parse it in their constructors separately
- Turn `ApiResponse` into a class with generics (`ApiResponse<T>`, where `data` is of type `T`). You will also have to pass a function that can parse the data json if you go with this approach.

Personally, I think it is overkill to use generics for this, but I wanted to mention it as a possible solution. With that in mind, you could do something like the following:

```dart
class ApiResponseBase {
  bool success;
  String message;

  ApiResponse({this.success, this.message});

  ApiResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    success = json['success'];
    message = json['message'];
  }
}

class ApiResponseArray extends ApiResponseBase {
  List<Data> data;

  ApiResponseArray.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) : super.fromJson(json) {
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data.add(new Data.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }
}

class ApiResponseObject extends ApiResponseBase {
  Data data;

  ApiResponseObject.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) : super.fromJson(json) {
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = new Data.fromJson(json['data']);
    }
  }
}
```

Note how I removed data from the `ApiResponseBase` because it is now being parsed in the derived classes.

If you really dislike the fact that there are now two definitions of data, you could use generics without needing to increase complexity:

```
class ApiResponseBase<T> {
  bool success;
  String message;
  T data;
  // same as before 
}

class ApiResponseArray extends ApiResponseBase<List<Data>> {
  // same as before
}

class ApiResponseObject extends ApiResponseBase<Data> {
  // same as before
}
```

But it works either way.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I'm looking for. One doubt is that Can I use  `userDetails` class in place of `ApiResponseObject` and `UsersListObject` class in place of `ApiResponseArray` directly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you just asking if you can rename the classes? If so, you can definitely change the names to whatever you want and it won't affect functionality. Just be sure that you rename it in every place you use it (if you're using a good IDE, they have rename or refactor features that take care of this for you)

Comment: No, I'm not asking for renaming the class. I would like to create model1 with `response1 -> data[0]` and model2 with `response2 -> data`  that both extends `ApiResponseBase` model.

Comment: So that I would (de)serialize json only with `Model1` and `Model2`. The `ApiResponseBase` props will be added automatically

Comment: I am not really sure what you're describing. What do `data` / `data[0]` represent? What do you mean regarding the props being added automatically -- isn't that obtained "for free" by extending the class?

Comment: `data / data[0]` is the objects in the json responses attached in the question. PFA. Consider those `data` objects as separate models because I have not added those properties in `ApiResponse`. I mentioned this in question also **"I would like to reuse the ApiResponse model for both calls by extending the data as separate models"**

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to check my current ApiResponseModel:

```dart
// api_response_model.dart

class ApiResponseModel<T> {
  const ApiResponseModel({
    this.OK,
    this.data,
  });

  factory ApiResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ApiResponseModel(
      OK: json['OK'],
      data: json['data'],
    );
  }

  final bool OK;
  final T data;
}


// avatar_repository.dart (use example)

final avatarResponse =
          ApiResponseModel<List<dynamic>>.fromJson(response.json()).data;

      final avatars = avatarResponse
          .map((avatar) => AvatarModel.fromJson(avatar))
          .toList();

// area_repository.dart (another example)

final area = ApiResponseModel<AreaModel>.fromJson(response.json()).data;

// user_repository.dart (complex cases)

final user = ApiResponseModel<dynamic>.fromJson(response.json()).data;
return UserModel.fromJson(user);
```

Comment: Is there any way to do like this `ApiResponseModel<UserModel>.fromJson(response.json())`